# Any library to symbolically solve system of PDEs in the form of expansion series?

Tags: library, math

I would like to use expansion series, more specifically power series, to solve a system of partial differential and algebraic equations (not sure what to call it, DAE or ADE?!)

I have found some [nice references](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1206/1206.2346.pdf) on the internet exploring the possibility, but in the end it is a pain to find the coefficients manually. So I used Maxima/WxMaxima symbolic CAS simplification commands, `rat() ratsimp() fullratsim()`..., but I still get pretty complicated output. For example if I have two independent variables `x` and `t` what I get is in the form of `$P_0(t)+P_1(t)x+P_2(t)x^2...$` but what I want is in the form of `$a_{0,0}+a_{1,0}x+a_{0,1}t+a_{1,1}xt...$`. Even having a nice output polynomial it is a still a hassle to list all the system of nonlinear equation of coefficients and then solving them.

I was thinking if there are any libraries which could do this automatically. What I'm looking for is

- a symbolic library for Python (Sympy), C/C++ (SymbolicC++, SymEngine, GiNaC...), Maxima, Julia ...
- which is able to get several PDE expressions, boundary/initial conditions in the form of points or symbolic functions, and a number as the order of the required output polynomial
- and then returns an approximate solution in the form of an expansion series `$\sum\left( a_{i,j,k,...}x_1^ix_2^jx_3^k... \right)$` up to the order specified before

I know it might be a pretty long shot but it worth a try before I go writing it myself. maybe other people have already though about it?

P.S.

1. Sorry if the equations are not being shown correctly, this post was moved here without my consent!
2. So far I have found [this tutorial](http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=4966&view=html) to solve an ODE in Maple